# javascript - what is the error with this code?

Tags: jquery

This is a part of a javascript code that is working good.
But I want to display the variable options in //Ex2 line:

```
if(profId==10){
    //alert(profId);
    $("#div_sel_residentType").show( "slow" );

    var selectElm="<label for=\"sel_residentType\">Sélectionniez le Type du Résident:</label><select class=\"form-control\" id=\"sel_residentType\"><option value=\"0\" selected=\"\">Type Résident</option>";
    var options ="";
    $.get("../api/v1/get/menus/typeresident.json.php", function(dataset, status){
        for (var index in dataset){ 
            options = options + "<option value=\""+dataset[index].id+"\">"+dataset[index].description+"</option>";
            //console.log(options);
        }
        console.log(options);//Ex1
    });

    console.log(options);//Ex2
    selectElm =  selectElm + options + "</select>";
    //console.log(selectElm);
    //$("#div_sel_residentType").html(selectElm);
}
```

I would like to understand why it displays `console.log(options);//Ex1` but not  `console.log(options);//Ex2`

Comment: `Ex2` executes immediately after the `$.get` call. `Ex1` executes after the call has received a response.

Comment: `$.get` is asynchronous, which means that the function you hand over to it will be called when the response is available. In the meantime your code will already proceed to be executed, coming to //Ex2 where options is still "".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That ajax call is `async` meaning that value does not exists on `Ex2` at that moment. Solution for that is to use `deferred` object take a look at this page : [DOC](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/)

Example from link :

> Since the jQuery.get method returns a jqXHR object, which is derived
>   from a Deferred object, we can attach a success callback using the
>   .done() method.

Full example from you code :

```
var options = "";
var defObj = $.get("../api/v1/get/menus/typeresident.json.php", function(dataset, status) {
      for (var index in dataset) {
        options = options + "<option value=\"" + dataset[index].id + "\">" + dataset[index].description + "</option>";
        //console.log(options);
      }
      console.log(options); //Ex1
    }); 

// get something done after ajax respone
defObj.done(function() {
    console.log(options); //Ex2
    selectElm = selectElm + options + "</select>";
});
```

or you can do it in single line :

```
$.get(/*...*/).done(/*...*/);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$.get(...)` initiates an *asynchronous* call. So execution will continue with the following statement, and only later (once the GET request has completed) will the callback be executed.

So the `console.log(options);//Ex2` line is executed *before* `options` is populated. So it's equivalent to `console.log("")`.

Comment: yes.. it is true.. how to make the callback after $get()?

Comment: Ok dont worry... I just put a .done() and solved. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log(options); //Ex2
```

This actually executes first.  And look how the variable `options` is defined:

```
var options = "";
```

So if you are looking for something to print to the console, it is just white space so nothing will show up.